# Capture All DNS Traffic

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, wildcard

I have a system that receives many different DNS requests every day from unauthorized users. What I need is a method to accept all DNS requests made to to this system and give back them back the same IP. Think of this as a gateway situation, where regardless of their DNS request, it will hand back the same IP.

Is it possible to do this through BIND? or is there a better more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [evldns](http://code.google.com/p/evldns/) framework could do this trivially and with the minimum of memory overhead, if you've got a Linux box available.

A plugin that always gives out a specific IP would only take a dozen or so lines of code.

If you can wait a day or so I might even write it myself...

**EDIT** - I've now done this - if you look at the `mod_arec.c` and `fixed.c` modules there's a demo of how to always return a specific IP address for any inbound `IN A foo` query.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use iptables to redirect all port 53 traffic to wherever it needs to go.

Comment: yes, but I am trying to capture this traffic, not redirect it to another DNS server. basically I want anyone who makes a DNS request of my server to get an answer, but it needs to answer the same for ALL requests

Comment: Then you might want to rewrite your question not to use the word "redirect"...

Answer (score 0):

The best answer, in my opinion, is going to be to whip one up in the programming language of your choice.  It's easy enough to do in python using `twisted.names`.

Comment: so you're suggesting writing my own program that will just accept all and punt back our default answer?

Comment: @Tedd - no need - I've written one for you...

Comment: Yes, I am.  Unless Alnitak's answer works better :)

Answer (score 0):

It's called a wildcard DNS record, and yes, it's doable with Bind and possibly other servers too.

Google it, or at least see [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record). It's pretty trivial after all.

Comment: Google it isn't an acceptable answer here. The point of SF is to have the answers listed here so that it is a static source of information. Linking to external sources as a reference is encouraged, but not as an entire answer.